# Use of SuperClass / Inheritance / Constructor Issue

Tags: java

I'm working on a small project.  There will be a Main Abstract class for booking, and two subclasses, one for Hotel Bookings and the other for Flight booking both of which inherit methods from the abstract class, such as Names / Addresses of the user etc.

While trying to create a constructor for a new hotel booking, I'm having an issue inheriting the methods/variables from the abstract class using the super() function.

The Error:

```
Constructor in class booking can not be applied to given types.
```

And here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


abstract class Booking{


  private String fname;
  private String lname;
  private int HouseNo;
  private String Street;
  private String Postcode;


  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


  //Parameterized Constructor
  Booking(String FirstName, String Lastname, int Housenumber, String thestreet, String 
  thePostcode)                       

  {
   fname = FirstName;
   lname = Lastname;
   HouseNo = Housenumber;
   Street = thestreet;
   thePostcode = Postcode;
   }




   //Acessor Methods below
   String getfname()
  {
 fname = "sds";
 return fname;
 }

 void setFname(String FirstName)
 {
fname = FirstName;
}

 String getlname()
 {
 return lname;
 }

 void setLname(String LastName)
 {
 lname = LastName;
 }

 int getHouseNo()
 {
 return HouseNo;
 }

 void setHouseNo(int HouseNumber)
 {
 HouseNo = HouseNumber;
 }

String getStreet()
 {
 return Street;
 }

 void setStreet(String StreetName)
 {
 Street = StreetName;
 }

String getPostcode()
 {
 return Postcode;
 }

 void setPostcode(String ThePostcode)
   {
 Postcode = ThePostcode;
 }


abstract public String Verification();
{
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Hotel extends Booking{



Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

private String TheVerification;
private int guests;
private String Roomtype;

Hotel(){
    super();
    TheVerification = Verification();
    guests = 0;
    Roomtype = Roomtype();
}

public String Verification(){
    System.out.println("Please provide your car reg as verification");
    TheVerification = in.next();
    return TheVerification;

}

public String Roomtype(){   
    System.out.println("Would you like a Premiun or Regular room?");
    Roomtype = in.next();
    return Roomtype;
}



public void print(){
    System.out.println("Roomtype" + Roomtype);

}


}
```

Comment: You don't have to specifically call the constructor from the superclass. Have you tried without that ?

Comment: I'm wanting the Sub class's constructor to make use of the super classes methods.. or am i barking up the wrong tree. Essentially on program interaction, the user will make use of the constructor in the Hotel side , inputting all the elements required. The idea for me having the abstract class is to prevent things being written out twice, and making use of one is a requirement of the project. (Essentially create a program including X,Y,Z) if I've tackled this the wrong way please say so, can only learn from mistakes ..

Comment: @Catalin What? If you provide your own ctor, how would the super ctor be called?

Comment: And try to avoid those ugly wordplays. Use `this` instead. Example: `this.firstName = firstName`.

Comment: When your constructor from Hotel is called, the first thing that happens there, is a call to the constructor in the Booking class (super()). So the _super()_ call in your constructor has no use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because there is no default constructor in `Booking`. When you call `super` from an inheriting class' constructor there has to be an appropriate constructor to call.

So, when you do:

```
Hotel() {
   super();
}
```

That constructor is looking for a constructor like this in `Booking`:

```
Booking() { 
   ...
}
```

However, `Booking` only has this constructor:

```
Booking(String FirstName, String Lastname, int Housenumber, String thestreet, String 
  thePostcode) {
    fname = FirstName;
    lname = Lastname;
    HouseNo = Housenumber;
    Street = thestreet;
    thePostcode = Postcode;
 }
```

So, you either need to create a default constructor in `Booking` or change your `Hotel` constructor to pass arguments, like so:

```
Hotel(String FirstName, String Lastname, int Housenumber, String thestreet, String 
  thePostcode) {
      super(FirstName, Lastname, Housenumber, thestreet, thePostcode);
      ...
 }
```

However, I think you should just reconsider your class hierarchy. Is a `Hotel` really a subclass of a `Booking` or should a `Hotel` contain many `Booking` instances?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'd tried something similar but was having issues, especially with the calling of certain variables later on in the program, however this was due to my own stupidity at how the program runs as opposed to any actual issue, my regards.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call a no-arg ctor on the base class, but none exists. Once you define a ctor with args the default no-arg ctor "goes away". Either provide a no-arg ctor for `Booking`, or call the one with parameters from the sub-class.

---

Java methods conventionally begin with a lower-case letter; I'd recommend following convention  to improve readability. Parameters and non-static-final properties should also begin with a lower-case.

Comment: Cheers for that I had looked at including a constructor that was simply Booking(){}, but confusion over how i would then reference elements of the super class such as fname/Firstname had me stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Booking` only has one constructor that takes a few arguments. Your class `Hotel` tries to call a constructor without any arguments (`super()`) which simply does not exist.

You'll need to either add a non-arg constructor to `Booking` or have `Hotel`'s constructor call `super(...)` suppling the correct number (and types) of values. Usually your sub-class constructor will have similiar, the same or more arguments than your super-class constructor, depending on the reason of sub-classing.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling to a constructor you have not defined:

```
super();
```

will call to

```
Booking()
```

But that constructor doesn't exist since you have defined a parameted constructor. You have to create a default constructor at Booking or call the parameted constructor from the subclass

Comment: Thanks for that - makes a lot of sense.